# Problem with CSV download to IE 6

Tags: asp.net

I have a friend experiencing problems testing a web site of mine that provides a CSV export for a report.  He says the CSV is output to the screen, and no file is created.

It works fine on my IIS7, Vista, and IE7 setup.  I can't get more details at the moment, but I'd like to at least ask: is my code, below, for sending the CSV adequate to be browser/version independent?

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    string fileName = GetExportFileName();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName);
    dt.WriteCsv(Response.Output, false);
    Response.End();
```

I'm building fileName to include a date with `/`separators, which may be causing a problem, but it doesn't affect my machine, and the `/` gets automagically replaced with `_`.

Comment: when are you writing the response??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also used

`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.csv");`

which adds the "attachment" text. You might try that to see if it makes any difference for your friend.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem in IE6 that do not correctly support the content-disposition meta tag and there are some gotchas in how to compose the various meta tags.

[This link from Scott Hanselman details everything about the issue.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx)

Regards
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party very here, so this is more for anyone who came across this issue at a later time. This is in relation to quote "*No HTTP header will force IE6 to offer a download.*"

In PHP I have the headers set as the following for IE to show a 'Save' button, and not just download the file - or display the file in the brower window.

```
Response.AddHeader("X-Download-Options", "noopen");
Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
```

The X headers are used to indicate that it is a non-standard header type. Works in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

The only sure fire way to get IE to prompt for a download is to have the CSV file compressed (ie file.csv.zip or file.zip).

See

- http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/02/01/364581.aspx
- [Handling MIME Types in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148(VS.85).aspx)
- [MIME Type Detection in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx#introduction)

No HTTP header will force IE6 to offer a download. This is especially true for text content, which is 'auto-detected' by IE.

You can try with Content-Disposition attachment; filename=file.csv but I'm not certain it'll always work. If it does, please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what browser your friend is using. In the end, it could be a bug or non-standard behavior.

The following technique seems to work fine for me: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/creating-downloadable-content-dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, all info is helpful, but I have already solved this by adding the content-disposition header, as shown in the accepted answer.